# How to can angularjs controller access functions in a non-angularjs iframe?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, iframe

I'm trying to have an angularjs controller access javascript functions in a non-angularjs iframe. I don't know where to start. Looking for guidance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you want the controller to access the functions, and what specifically you're trying to do?

Comment: OK,, This was a generic question for the most part.. But, I want to use CesiumJs in an iframe and drive it from an angualrjs app.. CesiumJS is a 3Dmap viewer with hundreds of APIs to call, listing each one I want to use is a bit overwhelming for everyone

Answer (score 1):

normally to communicate with an iFrame is to use window.postMessage, which enables cross-origin communcation, and on the receiving end, in your case, the window which has your angular code, you can use angular.element($window).on("message", function() to do whatever you want.

```
angular.module('windowExample', [])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {

  angular.element($window).on("message", function(e){
                    alert(e.data);
    }); 
}]);
```

A sample js fiddle is the following. Obviously I cannot really use an iFrame, so i used a button to fake the message

http://jsfiddle.net/atozaxsv/22/

Let me know

Comment: Hi dshun...  Thanks for the example...  I'll let you know in a bit :)